# Should I always use width for new line in div?

Tags: css, html

I am very new to HTML and hesitate before posting this question, because it very simple looking problem, but I am not getting good answer after Googling.

So following is my simple form code, I wanted to keep both the form input elements in different line. Problem is I literally need to use hardcoded **250px** width to div, so that element will code in different lines.

How do I improve my code so it will be portable across different browsers and screens?

Secondly, distance between all the lines in very less, they are actually collapsing on each other. How to give more vertical space to elements?

```html
    <form id="frm">
        <div style="width: 250px;">
    
            <label>Name </label>
            <input type="text" required="required" />
    
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="pranit@gmail.com" />
            
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float the label and inputs and specify 50% width with border-box box sizing method. You also need a wrapper element for each label-input pair which is used to contain the floats.

```css
form > div {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label,
input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form id="frm">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="pranit@gmail.com" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it seems to work. Two questions, 1) I need label and its input text in same line, block is making everything in next line. 2) How you get this 'Run code snippet' with you answer?

Comment: Same line? Change the widths to 50%/50% as use floats (I'll edit answer). And use the code snippet button (CTRL+M) to insert a "fiddle".

Answer (score 1):

If you want each label/input pair to appear on a line of its own, you should make that happen in markup using elements that actually cause line breaks, such as wrapping each of the pairs in a `div` or `p` element, or using `<br>` between them, or making each of them a row of a table. It is very unreliable to set just a width on a block and expect browsers to automatically wrap lines. Consider e.g. what happens in your example if the user sets font size to 60px (maybe due to eyesight problems).

To set vertical spacing, use CSS. There are many ways to do that, and the techniques partly depend on the markup chosen. Here is one example:

```html
<style>
td { padding-bottom: 0.5em; }
</style>
<form id="frm">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <td>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required="required">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <td>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email"
               placeholder="someone@example.com">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice answer, at many places I have read using table is not a good idea in HTML? +1.

Answer (score 0):

`label` tags and `input` tags are `inline` by default. You can set them both to `display: block` to make them stack. You can also add some `margin` to space them out:

```
label, input{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/74nxoa8y/)

**OR**

If you want the `label` and `input` inline but each one stacked, you can simply wrap them with a block element like a `div`:

```
<form id="frm">
    <div>
        <div>
            <label>Name </label>
            <input type="text" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="pranit@gmail.com" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/74nxoa8y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

1) you can define the `diplay` style for the `label` to `block`, this will bring label onto new line,

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/rvg4jdbo/

```
label{

    display:block;
}


<form id="frm">
    <div>

        <label>Name </label>
        <input type="text" required="required" />

        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="pranit@gmail.com" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

2) Or if you want to keep the label with the input element, then just add a div element between them http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/rvg4jdbo/1/

Answer (score 0):

If each element (labels and inputs) has to have own line, set them `display: block;`

```
#frm label, #frm input {display: block}
```

or

```
#frm div > * {display: block;}
```

If you need to have the `label` and `input` on one line, you can try to work with floats and clear.

```
label, input {float: left;}
label {width: 80px; clear: left;} /* set width to align inputs and clear to 'set' a new line */
```

Answer (score 0):

First use block elements for vertical placement of elements.

label{

```
display:block;
```

}

Use width in percentages not pixels if you can. It will keep it better, specially if they are in same line(inline).

```
<p style="width:50%"> </p> <p style="width:50%"> </p>
```

Can use media queries too for different resolutions.